# 25 frames per seconds and 30 frames per seconds footage in one seq

Tags: premiere, framerate, adobe

I filmed a short interview with 2 cameras. one shots in 25 fps and the other in 30 fps. When I open the sequence in Premiere I have to choose one frame rate and then one of the clips is out of sync.

I use the sound only from one camera and have problems with the sync.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Jonathan

Comment: Fix how?  What result do you want?  Are you hoping for a variable-FPS output video, where it's 30fps for clips from that source, and 25 for clips from the other?  That's perfectly valid, and containers like mp4 and mkv can store proper frame times.  The problem is that I think most video NLEs don't support doing that.  (The problem for an NLE is how to support a fade from one clip to another, rather than a cut.  So it would need a whole special mode for working with different-FPS sources.)

Comment: i want to export one video with sound in sink. Doesn't matter the frame rate. I nothinced that with some of the clip, the moment i import them to the premiere they get out of sink

Comment: "sync" is the word you want.  Sink is what you wash your hands in.  I don't know the answer to your problem, since I don't use Premiere.  If it will only work with clips of the same frame rate, then the only option is interpolating/duping or dropping frames from one to make it match the framerate of the other.  There's a limit to how good that can look (i.e. not very, unless interpolation is very smart.)

Comment: I'd be very interested to hear if there are any editors that can output variable-FPS videos, when cutting between clips of different framerates.  (or for slo-mo / sped-up effects).  Variable-FPS monitors are coming, and software support for VFR playback has existed for years already, at least in ffmpeg/ mplayer (and now the mpv fork of mplayer).

Comment: VFR playback may have existed for years, but unless you know exactly that your audience is using software / hardware that supports it, it sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 1):

The surest way to make this work is to convert one set of material so the two have matching frame rates. No frame rate conversion is perfect, but moving from 25 to 30 is more likely to look better because no frames need to be dropped. Instead you'll get interpolated or repeated frames. Be sure that your "30 fps" is really 30.00 and not 29.97 before you start. Premiere should tell you, but you can also use [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/) or other standalone tool

If Premiere can do rate conversion use it; otherwise try **ffmpeg** or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Premiere should be able to deal with source material that has different frame rates in the same sequence.

In your project window, right click the footage and choose `Modify>Interpret Footage`.

[image]

In the dialogue that appears you should be able to [specify a frame rate](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/organizing-assets-project-panel.html#change_the_frame_rate_of_a_clip) for the material. If this is set correctly Premiere will interpolate the footage to match the frame rate of any sequence it is cut into, without slowing it down or speeding it up, so theoretically the sound should stay in sync. In the best of all possible worlds, that is.

[image]